# Toon node with indirect lighting?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine

Trying to make a cellshaded shader in eevee which will also show blue light which comes from emissive blue objects next to it. Before I switched to the shader I made (screenshot) I was able to bake indirect lighting. Now it only shows as bright space on the color ramp. I'm kinda clueless about nodes so help is greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run your setup back through a Diffuse BSDF before connecting it to the Material output.

[image: ToonShade]